# Check (byte by byte) if two files are equal, using open(), read() in C

Tags: c

I know how to check if two files have the same content. I made it using `fopen` and `fread`. However, I have some problems translating the code and use `open` and `read` instead of `fopen` and `fread`.

When I run the program like this: `./app file1.txt file2.txt` (and files are not equal) program shows the message that they are not equal, and thats perfectly correct. When I try `./app file1 file1` instead, it also shows that the files are NOT equal, which is not true for sure. Another thing is that using `Code::Blocks` it shows me the return code `255` so I thing I messed something up, but do not what exactly.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int CompareFileByteByByte(char *file1, char *file2)
{
    int results = 0, c1, c2, br1, br2;
    int fin1 = -1, fin2 = -1;

    fin1 = open(file1, O_RDONLY);
    fin2 = open(file2, O_RDONLY);

    if (fin1 == -1)
    {
        perror ("open");
        return -1;
    }

    if (fin2 == -1)
    {
        perror ("open");
        return -1;
    }

    br1 = read (fin1, &c1, 1);
    br2 = read (fin2, &c2, 1);

    while((br1 > 0) && (br2 > 0) && results)
    {
        br1 = read (fin1, &c1, 1);
        br2 = read (fin2, &c2, 1);
        results = (c1 == c2);

        printf("%c %c\n", c1, c2);
    }

    close(fin1);
    close(fin2);

    return results;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Example usage:\n\n\t %s file1 file2\n\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s %s\n", argv[1], argv[2]);

        if(CompareFileByteByByte(argv[1], argv[2]))
        {
            printf("Files are equal\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Files are NOT equal\n");
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you try to compare file1 and a copy of file1?

Comment: @mch: Yes, I did - the result is the same as described here: it shows that those files are NOT equal, and the return value of the program is 255, instead of 0.

Comment: I'm not sure if your code is fit to compare a file with itself: before all, it is meant to work on two different files.

Comment: just a thought. are c1, c2 pointers or the words(bytes) being compared? maybe you should use results = (*c1 == *c2);

Comment: using `read` to read a single byte is very inefficient. Use `stdio` to buffer the reading

Comment: Should `c1` and `c2` by `char` and not `int`

Comment: Again a perfect opportunity to use a debugger. Do it, it's fun! :-)

Comment: @EdHeal: it helped, but still there is a problem with the return status code, its 255 instead of 0. How to deal with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never enter to the loop because of results is 0

```
 while((br1 > 0) && (br2 > 0) && results)
```

Comment: plus he not handle case when one file if prefix of another

Comment: After the *first* `br2 = read...` line, you need `results = (br1 == br2) && (c1 == c2);`. And you need a similar fix at the end as well (in case one file is longer than the other, you can't just stop comparing when one file ends).

Comment: Stil, `Files are NOT equal` and it returns 255

Comment: You have lots of bugs. At least four.